# Replace values in one column, depending on values in another column

Tags: python, dictionary, replace

```
import pandas as pd

dict = {
    '1': 'Alb',
    '2': 'Bnk',
    '3': 'Cd'
}

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'col1': {
            0: 20,
            1: 2,
            2: 10,
            3: 2,
            4: 44
        }, 
        'col2': {
            0:'a',
            1:'b',
            2:'c',
            3:'b',
            4:20
        }
     }
)
```

I want to replace `col1` value 2 with `'Bnk'` if `col2 value == 'b'`

How can this be done?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this but for clarity you can use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html?highlight=dataframe%20apply#pandas.DataFrame.apply):

```
import pandas as pd

dict = {
    1: 'Alb',
    2: 'Bnk',
    3: 'Cd'
}

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'col1': {
            0: 20,
            1: 2,
            2: 10,
            3: 2,
            4: 44
        }, 
        'col2': {
            0:'a',
            1:'b',
            2:'c',
            3:'b',
            4:20
        }
     }
)

def change(data, col2val, dict):
    if data['col2'] == col2val:
        data['col1'] = dict[data['col1']]

    return data

new_df = df.apply(change, axis = 1, col2val = 'b', dict = dict)

print(new_df)
```

I also modified the `dict` to have integer keys for simplicity.

**Output:**

```
  col1 col2  
0   20    a  
1  Bnk    b  
2   10    c  
3  Bnk    b  
4   44   20
```